How to render customimagenode using @react-sigma/core
I am using @react/sigma-core to render svgs as images. The problem is, my svg is getting cropped. i am not able to load full image. i tried using settings but nothing seems to work. any suggestions? i tried to render customimage like in https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/main/packages/storybook/stories/custom-rendering/index.ts but not sure how to work with customimage. any help will be appreciated
My setting is like so:
  const sigmaSettings = {
    allowInvalidContainer: true,
    defaultNodeType: 'image',
    stagePadding: 60,
    layout: 'forceAtlas2',
    edgeHoverColor: null,
    enableHovering: false,
    nodeHoverColor: 'transparent',
    nodeHoverSizeRatio: 1,
    defaultNodeSize: 10,
    zoomEnabled: false,
    cameraSettings: { ratio: 0.5 },
    // nodeProgramClasses: CustomNodeRenderer,
    nodeProgramClasses: {
      image: NodeImageProgram,
      // pictogram: NodePictogramProgram,
    },
    minEdgeSize: 3,
    maxEdgeSize: 3,
    scale: 0.09,
    defaultEdgeType: 'straight',
    edgeProgramClasses: {
      straight: EdgeArrowProgram,
      curved: EdgeCurvedArrowProgram,
    },
  };

My sample graph node is
graph.addNode(`${svg.x}.${svg.y}`, {
        x: svg.x + 50,
        y: svg.y + 30,
        size: 50,
        color: 'white',
        image: svgToDataURI(svg.val),
        type: 'image',
      });

If i increae size, image is zoomed and on decrease also it doesnt work

const NodePictogramCustomProgram = createNodeImageProgram({
  objectFit: 'contain',
});

This fixes the issue

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
